# Bad hyperref highlighting for biblatex citations

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, biblatex-sbl

I am using the `hyperref` package to highlight URLs, abbreviations, and shorthand in citations for convenience in a document, and I am using `biblatex-sbl` to get citations in SBL format. The `hyperref` package generally does a great job highlighting things like the `shortjournal` or `shortseries` fields in citations, but it seems to trip up when it tries to highlight the `shorttitle` field of an `article` citation: the opening quote of the short article title is highlighted with the rest of the title, but the close quote is not.

[image: Minimal (non-)working example]

For the sake of reproducibility, I've attached some code for a minimal (non-)working example, which consists of a bibliography file and a TeX file.

```
bibliography.bib

@article{
    MWE20,
    author = {Joey McCollum},
    title = {A Minimal (Non-)Working Example},
    shorttitle = {MWE},
    journal = {TeX Stack Exchange Quarterly},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {1--2}
}
```

```
mwe.tex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Include support for hyperreferences:
\usepackage{hyperref}
%Include support for citation format:
\usepackage[style=sbl, ibidtracker=false, idemtracker=false, citepages=omit, backend=biber]{biblatex}
%Add the bibliography source file:
\addbibresource{./bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
    This is a minimal (non-)working example.\footnote{\cite{MWE20}.} It is intended to illustrate unexpected behavior in \LaTeX.\footnote{\cite[2]{MWE20}.}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I typeset this using the TeXLive 2020 release of pdfLaTeX and the corresponding release of XeLaTeX; both engines will reproduce this behavior.

I imagine the issue has something to do with substitutions made by `biblatex-sbl` to ensure that a comma following a title in quotes is placed within the quotes (in accordance with American English style), but I can't say for sure. As it is, the current highlighting is a bit ugly. If there was a way to highlight the shortened title more consistently, either by including both the surrounding quotes and the comma or by highlighting only the title itself, without the surrounding quotes and the comma, that would be great. Is there any easy way to fix this, or is it a bug that will have to be fixed in one of the packages involved?

EDIT: As moewe has pointed out in the comments, this has been a known bug in `biblatex` for a few years now (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/499), and it affects citation styles other than `sbl` (such as `verbose-note`).

Comment: I think this is basically this bug: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/499

Comment: Yes, that issue describes my problem exactly! Thanks for sharing this. It looks like this problem affects citation styles in `biblatex` other than SBL, too. Has it really been left unsolved since 2016?

Comment: It affects all styles where a link is applied with a field format outside another field format with quotation marks. The issue only occurs with US-style punctuation moving shenannigans for quotation marks. That's also why it is so difficult to resolve. (I have looked into this once or twice in the last years, but I always came to the conclusion that it is too difficult for me.)

Comment: @moewe can't you move the link inside the quote then?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In some (many?) instances you could swap the order of the formats, yes. E.g. `\printtext[citetitle]{\printfield[bibhyperlink]{...}}` instead of `\printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printfield[citetitle]{...}}` (for `verbose-note` as in the `biblatex` bug report). But of course that doesn't resolve the underlying problem. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: @moewe yes I meant this. I know it is not perfect but better than one quote in and the other out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting @UlrikeFischer and @moewe's solution does appear to work:

Try this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{MWE20,
  author = {Joey McCollum},
  title = {A Minimal (Non-)Working Example},
  shorttitle = {MWE},
  journal = {TeX Stack Exchange Quarterly},
  year = {2020},
  pages = {1-2}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=sbl, ibidtracker=false, idemtracker=false, citepages=omit, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{shorttitle}{%
  \iftoggle{blx@useshorttitle}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {\iffieldundef{title}
          {}
          {\ifbool{bbx@inset}
             {\printtext{\bibhyperlink{\strfield{setkey}}
                {\printtext[title]{\printfield[titlecase]{title}}}}}
             {\printtext[title]{%
                \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printfield[titlecase]{title}}}}}}
       {\ifbool{bbx@inset}
          {\printtext{\bibhyperlink{\strfield{setkey}}
             {\printtext[title]{\printfield[titlecase]{shorttitle}}}}}
          {\printtext[title]{%
             \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\printfield[titlecase]{shorttitle}}}}}%
     \newunit}
    {}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
This is a minimal (non-)working example \autocite{MWE20}. It is intended to
illustrate unexpected behavior in \LaTeX \autocite[2]{MWE20}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]