# BibLaTeX Quotation Marks Hyperlinked Inconsistently

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I was writing a paper with the package `biblatex-chicago`, and the package `enotez` was used to convert footnotes to endnotes, and this is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{urlblue}{rgb}{0.19,0.54,0.92}
\definecolor{winered}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% hyperref
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=winered,
    urlcolor=urlblue,
    citecolor=winered,
    anchorcolor=cyan,
    hyperfootnotes=true,
    ]{hyperref}

% Convert footnotes to endnotes
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{list-name={Bibliographies \& Notes},list-style=itemize,backref=true,totoc}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage[notes,abbreviate=true,doi=false,url=false,notetype=endonly,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
% Make the title of the bibliography section a hyperlink with DOI or URL if available
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48409/176776
\newbibmacro{string+doiurl}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}{%
    \iffieldundef{url}{\textquotedblleft#1\textquotedblright}%
        {\textquotedblleft\href{\thefield{url}}{#1}\textquotedblright}%
  }{%
    \textquotedblleft\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}\textquotedblright%
  }%
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection,online]{title}{\usebibmacro{string+doiurl}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{url}{}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

This is the first sentence\autocite[38]{vandergeest1995}.

The second citation\autocite[222]{kwon2010}

And a citation appears again\autocite[100]{vandergeest1995}.

% Endnotes
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

And this is the content of `bibliography.bib`:

```
@article{vandergeest1995,
  title = {Territorialization and State Power in {{Thailand}}},
  author = {Vandergeest, Peter and Peluso, Nancy Lee},
  date = {1995},
  journaltitle = {Theory and Society},
  volume = {24},
  number = {3},
  pages = {385--426},
  doi = {10.1007/BF00993352}
}

@book{kwon2010,
  title = {The {{Other Cold War}}},
  author = {Kwon, Heonik},
  date = {2010},
  publisher = {{Columbia University Press}},
  location = {{New York}},
  doi = {10.7312/kwon15304}
}
```

With the LaTeX code above, if a bibliography item has appeared, later it is cited again will be linked to the location of the first one with the simplified format, which is a good implementation I love a lot. However, this encountered an issue regarding quotation marks.
As the screenshot shows below, the left quotation mark was hyperlinked, while the right one didn't. However, I'd make both unclickable (or vice versa), how can I make it? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: report it to the author of biblatex-chicago.

Comment: I haven't yet had a closer look at this, but I suspect it has to do with the US punctuation code to move punctuation inside quotation marks. In that case https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/499 would be related. But the implementation of all of that is pretty tricky, so I don't think I can promise a proper solution short-term.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for your reply. I've tried the workaround you have linked. It worked for `biblatex` package, while not well with `biblatex-chicago` package. Additionally, the workaround (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551014/176776) made it conflict with my existing code to hyperlink DOI or URL above. Hope there is a general solution to this issue. Thanks again.